# How to hide #document (Public URL) in browser source code that has already been encrypted?

Tags: angular, url, powerbi, hide

The public URL of the powerbi report was already encrypted so that it does not appear in the browser's source code, but it began to appear in the #document tag recently, this tag is created automatically once the system made in angular, node v16.13.1 is published.

[I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGZ4w.png)

The URL encryption was made so that it would not be displayed in the browser's source code, but recently it started appearing that way in #document. The tests carried out have not been successful in hiding this label.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.